# Using debugger breakpoints in Edx-Discovery with docker

Tags: docker, debugging, nose, edx

I am currently setting up `Edx-Discovery` with dockers. and it is working perfectly.
https://github.com/edx/course-discovery

Down the line, I had to use breakpoints for debugging, I used `nose.tools` but I was unable to use the debugger, it stopped somewhere though but I had no control to check the values of the variables.

`from nose.tools import set_trace;set_trace()`

Now, My question is, is there anyway, I can have breakpoints in dockers like we use it normally in a programming language? 
Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement has been updated in edx dockers stack. Now for debugging tools, use the following command.

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```